# MPAndroidChart starting bars in other place than 0

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Id like to achive someting like this where more negative values appear below less negative. Is it possible for bars to start in other place than 0.
chart.getAxisLeft().setInverted(true);
does not do what i want.

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyrKV.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can control the span of Y axis by two functions from [`AxisBase`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/AxisBase.java):

[`public void setAxisMinimum(float min)`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/AxisBase.java#L667)

[`public void setAxisMaximum(float max)`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/AxisBase.java#L690)

Just iterate through values, choose minimum and maximum values and set Y axis min and max values:

In the case of provided example:

```
mChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(-112f);
mChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaximum(-12f);
```

Comment: It wont work in this case, bar starts at 0 and if i just set negative values as min and max bar will come from top of the chart, and i dont want that

Comment: @Efka were you able to achieve this? I am also having the same issue.I want the bar to start from the smallest negative value in the chart, but it starts from top to bottom.